# recursive mounts not visible in endpoint

Tags: linux, mount, recursive

I have a little (virtual) infrastructure with multiple servers - and some of these configuration I cannot change because of software restrictions. 2 of the servers are WEBservers, and a NAS-like server. In front of the webserver is a load-balancer (not question related, but for understanding).

The NAS has mounted a partition regurarly for files I'd like to serve the webservers. So I set up a NFS-share on it which is accessible by the webservers. In this way I can ensure that both webservers have the same files and I don't have to sync them in any way. For big files I'd like to mount an additional ressource inside the existing NFS share on the NAS (to be able to save them somewhere externally or for use with Amazon's A3). In my test setup I did just another partition and mounted it inside in a subfolder.

In the end, my NAS has a NFS share at let's say /mnt/data. In the NAS I have mounted the external ressource into /mnt/data/external. On the NAS server is everything fine. But when I take a look from the webservers view I cannot see the contents of folder 'external'. Also the mounted space size has not been increased.

Is my idea something impossible or am I missing something?

I'd like to see and manipulate files in that second mount from the webservers. A bit an odd configuration heh? Because of some restriction of the virtualisation software I have to do this like that. What I cannot change is the setup of the nfs-share for the connection between webservers and nas. So I try to find a way to include the external ressource inside it.

Thanks very much for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You want to take a look at the `nohide` option. As the manpage for [exports](http://linux.die.net/man/5/exports) says:-

> This option is based on the option of the same name provided in IRIX
>   NFS.  Normally, if a server exports two filesystems one of which is
>   mounted on the other, then the  client  will  have  to  mount  both 
>   filesystems explicitly to get access to them.  If it just mounts the
>   parent, it will see an empty directory at the place where the other
>   filesystem is mounted.  That filesystem is "hidden".

...which seems to describe exactly the behaviour you're seeing.

Adding `nohide` as an option to the export in `/etc/exports` should solve this.